# Does PHP optimize function arguments of array type, not explicitly passed by reference, when they are not modified?

Tags: php, arrays, optimization, php-internals

Would the PHP engine optimize the second example to pass the `$arr` by reference?

```
function test1(array &$arr)
{
    $arr[] = 123;

    echo $arr[0];
}

function test2(array $arr)
{
    echo $arr[0];
}
```

Comment: @u_mulder, to avoid of copying the whole array and consume less memory

Comment: Array will be copied when there's a need to do it.

Comment: Arguments passed to a function are only "copied" (copy-on-edit) if you actually change the value inside the function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PHP uses a mechanism called [copy-on-write](http://php.net/manual/de/internals2.variables.intro.php) to avoid exactly the excessive copying of variables as long as it's unnecessary to do so. So even in your `test2()` example `$array` is not copied at all. If you'd modified `$array` inside the function, PHP would have copied the variable to allow modification. A detailed explanation of this mechanism can be found in the ["Memory Management"](http://www.phpinternalsbook.com/zvals/memory_management.html) chapter of the ["PHP Internals Book"](http://www.phpinternalsbook.com/index.html). The following quote is from the ["Reference-counting and copy-on-write"](http://www.phpinternalsbook.com/zvals/memory_management.html#reference-counting-and-copy-on-write) section:

> If you think about the above for a bit, you’ll come to the conclusion
>   that PHP must be doing an awful lot of copying. Every time you pass
>   something to a function the value needs to be copied. This may not be
>   particularly problematic for an integer or a double, but imagine
>   passing an array with ten million elements to a function. Copying
>   millions of elements on every call would be prohibitively slow.
>
> To avoid doing so, PHP employs the copy-on-write paradigm: A zval can
>   be shared by multiple variables/functions/etc as long as it’s only
>   read from and not modified. If one of the holders wants to modify it,
>   the zval needs to be copied before applying any changes.

The following two articles provide even more insight into this topic (both written by PHP core developers):

- Johannes Schlüter: [Do not use PHP references](http://schlueters.de/blog/archives/125-Do-not-use-PHP-references.html)
- Sara Golemon: [You're being lied to](http://blog.golemon.com/2007/01/youre-being-lied-to.html)

The first one even explains why using references just for performance reasons is most often a bad idea:

> Another reason people use reference is since they think it makes the
>   code faster. But this is wrong. It is even worse: References mostly
>   make the code slower!
>
> Yes, references often make the code slower - Sorry, I just had to
>   repeat this to make it clear.

And the second one shows why objects are not really passed by reference in PHP5+.

Comment: Thanks! I don't think I was completely wrong, but you're definitely more correct :) Deleted my answer. Do you think there's any performance gain whatsoever by passing large arrays by reference if they're not modified?

Comment: @Will: See my updated answers. There is no performance gain in passing variables by reference explicitly - it's even worse: it makes the code slower. I've read somewhere: *don't try to outsmart the engine*.